# `ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error` when trying to train tensorflow model using model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

A few days back, I got the same error at 12th epoch. This time, it happens at the 1st. I have no idea why that is happening as I did not make any changes to the model. I only normalized the input to give `X_train.max()` as 1 after scaling like it should be.

Does it have something to do with patch size? Should I reduce it?

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

`my_model.summary()`

```
Model: "U-Net"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_6 (InputLayer)           [(None, 64, 64, 64,  0           []                               
                                 3)]                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_95 (Conv3D)             (None, 64, 64, 64,   5248        ['input_6[0][0]']                
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_90 (BatchN  (None, 64, 64, 64,   256        ['conv3d_95[0][0]']              
 ormalization)                  64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 activation_90 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 64,   0           ['batch_normalization_90[0][0]'] 
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_96 (Conv3D)             (None, 64, 64, 64,   110656      ['activation_90[0][0]']          
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_91 (BatchN  (None, 64, 64, 64,   256        ['conv3d_96[0][0]']              
 ormalization)                  64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 activation_91 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 64,   0           ['batch_normalization_91[0][0]'] 
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling3d_20 (MaxPooling3D  (None, 32, 32, 32,   0          ['activation_91[0][0]']          
 )                              64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_97 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32,   221312      ['max_pooling3d_20[0][0]']       
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_92 (BatchN  (None, 32, 32, 32,   512        ['conv3d_97[0][0]']              
 ormalization)                  128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 activation_92 (Activation)     (None, 32, 32, 32,   0           ['batch_normalization_92[0][0]'] 
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_98 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32,   442496      ['activation_92[0][0]']          
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_93 (BatchN  (None, 32, 32, 32,   512        ['conv3d_98[0][0]']              
 ormalization)                  128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 activation_93 (Activation)     (None, 32, 32, 32,   0           ['batch_normalization_93[0][0]'] 
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling3d_21 (MaxPooling3D  (None, 16, 16, 16,   0          ['activation_93[0][0]']          
 )                              128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_99 (Conv3D)             (None, 16, 16, 16,   884992      ['max_pooling3d_21[0][0]']       
                                256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_94 (BatchN  (None, 16, 16, 16,   1024       ['conv3d_99[0][0]']              
 ormalization)                  256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 activation_94 (Activation)     (None, 16, 16, 16,   0           ['batch_normalization_94[0][0]'] 
                                256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_100 (Conv3D)            (None, 16, 16, 16,   1769728     ['activation_94[0][0]']          
                                256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_95 (BatchN  (None, 16, 16, 16,   1024       ['conv3d_100[0][0]']             
 ormalization)                  256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 activation_95 (Activation)     (None, 16, 16, 16,   0           ['batch_normalization_95[0][0]'] 
                                256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling3d_22 (MaxPooling3D  (None, 8, 8, 8, 256  0          ['activation_95[0][0]']          
 )                              )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_101 (Conv3D)            (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  3539456     ['max_pooling3d_22[0][0]']       
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_96 (BatchN  (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  2048       ['conv3d_101[0][0]']             
 ormalization)                  )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_96 (Activation)     (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  0           ['batch_normalization_96[0][0]'] 
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_102 (Conv3D)            (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  7078400     ['activation_96[0][0]']          
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_97 (BatchN  (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  2048       ['conv3d_102[0][0]']             
 ormalization)                  )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_97 (Activation)     (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  0           ['batch_normalization_97[0][0]'] 
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling3d_23 (MaxPooling3D  (None, 4, 4, 4, 512  0          ['activation_97[0][0]']          
 )                              )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_103 (Conv3D)            (None, 4, 4, 4, 102  14156800    ['max_pooling3d_23[0][0]']       
                                4)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_98 (BatchN  (None, 4, 4, 4, 102  4096       ['conv3d_103[0][0]']             
 ormalization)                  4)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 activation_98 (Activation)     (None, 4, 4, 4, 102  0           ['batch_normalization_98[0][0]'] 
                                4)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_104 (Conv3D)            (None, 4, 4, 4, 102  28312576    ['activation_98[0][0]']          
                                4)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_99 (BatchN  (None, 4, 4, 4, 102  4096       ['conv3d_104[0][0]']             
 ormalization)                  4)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 activation_99 (Activation)     (None, 4, 4, 4, 102  0           ['batch_normalization_99[0][0]'] 
                                4)                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_transpose_20 (Conv3DTra  (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  4194816    ['activation_99[0][0]']          
 nspose)                        )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_20 (Concatenate)   (None, 8, 8, 8, 102  0           ['conv3d_transpose_20[0][0]',    
                                4)                                'activation_97[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_105 (Conv3D)            (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  14156288    ['concatenate_20[0][0]']         
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_100 (Batch  (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  2048       ['conv3d_105[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_100 (Activation)    (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  0           ['batch_normalization_100[0][0]']
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_106 (Conv3D)            (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  7078400     ['activation_100[0][0]']         
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_101 (Batch  (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  2048       ['conv3d_106[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 activation_101 (Activation)    (None, 8, 8, 8, 512  0           ['batch_normalization_101[0][0]']
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_transpose_21 (Conv3DTra  (None, 16, 16, 16,   1048832    ['activation_101[0][0]']         
 nspose)                        256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_21 (Concatenate)   (None, 16, 16, 16,   0           ['conv3d_transpose_21[0][0]',    
                                512)                              'activation_95[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_107 (Conv3D)            (None, 16, 16, 16,   3539200     ['concatenate_21[0][0]']         
                                256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_102 (Batch  (None, 16, 16, 16,   1024       ['conv3d_107[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 activation_102 (Activation)    (None, 16, 16, 16,   0           ['batch_normalization_102[0][0]']
                                256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_108 (Conv3D)            (None, 16, 16, 16,   1769728     ['activation_102[0][0]']         
                                256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_103 (Batch  (None, 16, 16, 16,   1024       ['conv3d_108[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 activation_103 (Activation)    (None, 16, 16, 16,   0           ['batch_normalization_103[0][0]']
                                256)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_transpose_22 (Conv3DTra  (None, 32, 32, 32,   262272     ['activation_103[0][0]']         
 nspose)                        128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_22 (Concatenate)   (None, 32, 32, 32,   0           ['conv3d_transpose_22[0][0]',    
                                256)                              'activation_93[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_109 (Conv3D)            (None, 32, 32, 32,   884864      ['concatenate_22[0][0]']         
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_104 (Batch  (None, 32, 32, 32,   512        ['conv3d_109[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 activation_104 (Activation)    (None, 32, 32, 32,   0           ['batch_normalization_104[0][0]']
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_110 (Conv3D)            (None, 32, 32, 32,   442496      ['activation_104[0][0]']         
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_105 (Batch  (None, 32, 32, 32,   512        ['conv3d_110[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 activation_105 (Activation)    (None, 32, 32, 32,   0           ['batch_normalization_105[0][0]']
                                128)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_transpose_23 (Conv3DTra  (None, 64, 64, 64,   65600      ['activation_105[0][0]']         
 nspose)                        64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_23 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64,   0           ['conv3d_transpose_23[0][0]',    
                                128)                              'activation_91[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_111 (Conv3D)            (None, 64, 64, 64,   221248      ['concatenate_23[0][0]']         
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_106 (Batch  (None, 64, 64, 64,   256        ['conv3d_111[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 activation_106 (Activation)    (None, 64, 64, 64,   0           ['batch_normalization_106[0][0]']
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_112 (Conv3D)            (None, 64, 64, 64,   110656      ['activation_106[0][0]']         
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization_107 (Batch  (None, 64, 64, 64,   256        ['conv3d_112[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                 64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 activation_107 (Activation)    (None, 64, 64, 64,   0           ['batch_normalization_107[0][0]']
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv3d_113 (Conv3D)            (None, 64, 64, 64,   260         ['activation_107[0][0]']         
                                4)                                                                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 90,319,876
Trainable params: 90,308,100
Non-trainable params: 11,776
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

Error Message Log:

```
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-ec522ff5ad08> in <module>()
      5           epochs=100,
      6           verbose=1,
----> 7           validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'U-Net/concatenate_23/concat' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
      handler_func(fileobj, events)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 452, in _handle_events
      self._handle_recv()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 481, in _handle_recv
      self._run_callback(callback, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 431, in _run_callback
      callback(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
      return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
      handler(stream, idents, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
      if self.run_code(code, result):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-52-ec522ff5ad08>", line 7, in <module>
      validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
packages/keras/layers/merge.py", line 531, in _merge_function
      return backend.concatenate(inputs, axis=self.axis)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 3313, in concatenate
      return tf.concat([to_dense(x) for x in tensors], axis)
Node: 'U-Net/concatenate_23/concat'
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[8,128,64,64,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node U-Net/concatenate_23/concat}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_24517]
```

GPU details:
`nvidia-smi` command:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   72C    P0    73W / 149W |  11077MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm new to Tensorflow and all of this ML stuff honestly. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: The first thing to do is to reduce the batch size

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same error as you ,it's a resource exhausted problem, resolved by just reducing batch_size value(I had a Model which try to learn from dataset of big images I reduce it's value from 32 to 16) .and it's worked fine

Answer (score 2):

1. Batch size reduction is worked for me (from 32 to 16)

> Note : Since, all the CPU/GPU comes with a storage capacity in power of two, it is advised to keep mini-batch size a power of two

2. Add less number of CPUs than total to device count. In my computer, there are 12 CPUs. when i use CPU count as 12, i got that error. it was fixed when it reduced to 10.

`tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto( device_count = {'GPU': 1 , 'CPU': 10}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need help here, but the problem is that you are loading the datasets using the GPU (I can see it from the nvidia-smi you provided, the GPU Memory is full), you have to specify that you want to use the CPU, so that the data can be sent in batches to the GPU. Lets say you are loading the data this way:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(path-to-file), shuffle=False)
```

you should instead do this:

```
with tf.device("CPU"):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(path-to-file), shuffle=False)
```

and remember that you must use the 'with tf.device("CPU")' every time you are using variable related to the dataset, otherwise it will be loaded on the GPU.

Answer (score -1):

Just by looking at your SS from `nvidia-smi` command, it seems like your GPU is not being used for this model training. So, you might wanna look into it and start using your GPU for computation during model training.